# extracting meaning out of graphs

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

i was given graph and five statements

and i was told to choose the correct statements based on the graph

in the graph is showing the weight of boys over time in the red line and of girls in the dotted blue line

and as i understand it the weight of 5% of the population is under the bottom graph same for the middle 50% graph and the top one 95%

[image]

the statements are:

1. in every age boys weight more then girls
2. a boy in age 4 that weighs 20 kg will weigh 80 kg in age 15
3. the average weight of boys at age 18 is about 70 kg
4. in both genders the growth rate is the highest at ages 0-1
5. the rate of growth in girls slows down around age 16 while boys keep growing until age 18

i think all statements are correct but i was told that was wrong

can anyone explain to me how do i read a graph like this?

and also what i got wrong about the statements.

Comment: If you have the chance, I would recommend giving _reasons_ for saying T or F for each one. Here are some thoughts, not necessarily answers.1 seems wrong because all red curves dip below dotted curves at some point. 2. The heaviest boy at age 4 may be the scrawniest at 15; these curves are for the population, not for individual kids. 3. "Average" usually denotes "mean" which is not the same as "median", but if weights are approx normal, this one may be true. 4. Hard to judge, but his one may be true. 5. Girls' growth seems to slow closer to 14 than 16. Don't know what that means about T or F.

Comment: how do i calculate the mean?

Comment: From the graph, there is no way to calculate the mean. I'm just saying that in a sample from a normal distribution, the mean and median are often nearly the same. I have no idea whether children's weights are normally distributed.